# Migrate kafka stream state store

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

We are migrating our kafka stream application to a new environment. What is the best way to migrate a large state store(around 1 billion records in changelog topic). Do we need to mirror the changelog topic(s) to the new kafka cluster first. Are there any other options/tools available. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried mirroring? How did that work for you?

Comment: Yes, you would need to mirror the corresponding topics.